# extjs Add item to store within controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my controller i have.

```
               'panel > button':{
                    click:function(){
                        console.log('button clicked')

                        var view = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#alexPanel')[0];

                        var modelItem = view.getPostValue() // i get the data from the form
                        //here i would like to update my store with a new item
                    }
                }
```

Thank you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
getXXXStore().add(modelItem);
```

Where XXX is the name of your store as configured in your controller's `stores` property.

Comment: Hi Johnny. i get me.mixins.elementCt is undefined when the store is imported as  stores:['app.store.GlobalStore'],

Comment: Dont know if its the best way but i did it with  grid.getStore().add(view.getPostValue())
Getting stro from the view that has it and adding the new item there.

Comment: @Trostik However you get the store is fine, there are multiple ways to  do that.